# Higher response times are observed in Jmeter Performance test when ran in AWS windows machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

While load/performance testing of an API on DNS in AWS using JMeter, we observed relatively higher response times(~ 230 ms) in AWS windows machine. When this test is performed in my local machine, the response times are around 110 ms.The throughput/# of samples served does change widely due to this response time.

The tests were ran for 1 hour each with no delay for three times in both the machines. The only difference I see is my RAM size is 16 GB while AWS is 4 GB. Will this really make such a big difference? or is there something I am missing.

AWS Machine configuration:

[image]

My local machine configuration:

[image]

Can anyone share their thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 possible reasons:

1. Your AWS machine is located in the [region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-available-regions) which is geographically more far from the endpoint than your local machine
2. It might really be the case JMeter lacks resources on the AWS instance and hence cannot send requests fast enough so make sure to:

- Monitor the resources available to JMeter using [Windows PerfMon](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/windows-performance-monitor-overview/ba-p/375481) or [Amazon Cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) or [JMeter Perfmon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)  as JMeter might be very resources intensive and it should heave sufficient headroom to operate
- Follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)